# fetch POST not reading sent request from react native properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, post, fetch-api

I'm not sure what's the actual problem here, could be the API, the fetch implementation on react native, or my formatting.

I tried so many different formats and even hard coded the request into my app but the server API I'm requesting from is still returning `Error 400: Bad Request` and a JSON file saying `unsupported_grant_type`.
here's the snippet of what I'm sending:

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "Authorization": "Basic TWVtYmVyQ2VudGVyTGFuZGluZzp0ZXN0cGFzcw==",
   },
   "data": {
     "grant_type": "password",
     "username": "MemberCenterLanding",
     "password": "testpass"
   }
}
```

Then I sent this using `fetch(url, options).then(response => { return response.json()...` with staging url `http://10.64.2.149:8081/oauth/token` based on the API documentation.

I tried this request with postman and it works, just not from my program :(
I tried changing the format of the body with `JSON.stringify()` and `FormData` as well but nothing works.

ADD: I also tried creating mini request files to be run on node.js using `node-fetch` and still not working and yielding to same result. Interestingly, `node-request` works fine.

Can anyone help me narrow down what's the problem here?
Is there any kind of alteration done by fetch() implementation of react native of maybe it has something to do with the way the API was implemented?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use `body` instead of data. and use `JSON.stringify` to converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string.

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "Authorization": "Basic TWVtYmVyQ2VudGVyTGFuZGluZzp0ZXN0cGFzcw==",
   },
   "body": JSON.stringify ({
     "grant_type": "password",
     "username": "MemberCenterLanding",
     "password": "testpass"
   }),
}
```